# no autocomplete DOCTYPE HTML vscode when pressing exclamation mark

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

When i typed `!` it should showed up like in the image;

[image: autocomplete]

But it doesn't work, is it because vscode gotten an update? Or do I have something wrong in my side?

I already have a solution by doing `html:5` but i still wanted to know if it's a bug or not.

I just started learning HTML and CSS 3 days ago so i'm still a newbie, thank you for reading.

Comment: Press tab or click on it

Comment: @Fork when i pressed `!` it did not show up the UI for the options.

Comment: I updated my VSCode and I don't seem to have any issues. I suggest going to your extensions tab and typing in @builtin and checking if emmet isn't disabled by mistake. If that doesn't work, I would suggest uninstalling your vscode and if you're comfortable with it locate the remainder files and delete them. Then download a fresh copy of vscode and install it again

Comment: @Fork my emmet is enabled, it seems i turned something to true/false accidentally. I'm currently trying to find the property, Thank you for helping me! I will update you to if i have solved my issue or not.

Comment: @Fork Please check the first answer in this post.

Comment: Great! There's a button where you can choose to answer your own question, you can use that so the question gets closed

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72914461/836330 it is a known issue with the latest release.  I don't think you changed any settings.

Answer (score 1):

i was a dummy.

As [@Fork](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18206501/fork) said in the comments, I need to check my 'emmet' settngs. That's where i just realized I turned off a bunch of useful stuff!

Sorry for making a stupid post!

Edit: As [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836330/mark) says in the comment it seems its the vscode update.