# Is there a way to reset defaults for Emmet in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

Strangest thing, as I use it regularly, for some strange reason, whenever I type:

ul>li*5 (any number) - emmet does nothing. It stops after the asterisk. Anything before it works fine.

Any ideas what I can try, or have broken?

Comment: Out of interest, if you highlight the bit you want to be expanded with emmet, then go to 'Edit' > 'Emmet: Expand Abbreviation' (at the bottom), does it work?

Comment: Ah... It did work, if I go through the menu to expand abbreviation. So apparently, it just isn't working with the return key.

Comment: It is a known issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72914461/836330.  Lots of reports on github.

Comment: I've been searching for about 30 minutes, never came across it. Good to know, and thanks! I also figured out it will work with the manual "option+spacebar" to show the abbreviation first

Comment: I'll close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try restarting vs code, or your computer. If you really care, you could try reinstalling vs code (although if the other two methods don't work, there's probably a better solution than reinstalling).

Comment: I did restart both, with no luck. Even new file, etc.. I did find that it will work if I go through the edit menu to "expand abbreviation"