# Emmet wont work as a enter tab, how to get it back?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, settings, extension-methods, emmet

I tried other solutions like this. https://dev.to/pranavarora1895/emmet-not-working-in-vs-code-heres-how-you-can-fix-this-problem-1367

in which i got this
[it wont let me save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qti78.png)

But it wont let me save the settings and it dosent work

I tried the regular settings that say extesion on tab but It dosent let me use the enter key and gives a ugly inline sugggestion. How do i get it back?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908218/some-emmet-abbrevirations-in-vsc-not-working-like-or-using it is a known issue.  Try the advice there.

Comment: oh has the issue just been started recently

Comment: thank toy for the link it is annyoing but works. thank you for your time also