# My html quick fill in vs code is not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut

My shortcuts like "tab + !" cannot generate the html example. I've tried change the language,but not working. And when typing "li*3 + tab", it used to quick fill. But now all not working.

PS: After I download VUE, all these happen. I don't know if it's related. And I've already delete and reinstall vscode.It's frustrating and I haven't find any question related.

Comment: I finally find out the solution. Vscode -- setting -- emmet:Trigger Expansion on Tab. Check it  and the shortcuts come back. I don't know why it's uncheck, but happy to help anyone has the same problem.

Comment: Duplicate , see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908218/some-emmet-abbrevirations-in-vsc-not-working-like-or-using/72914461#72914461.  Your fix doesn't help it work for me.