# Visual Studio Code HTML template with Exclamation Mark

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, settings, emmet

when I write ! but now auto complete HTML Template you can help me please

[if you look image you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMDz8.png)

Comment: the extension you're referring to has been shut down. i could recommend using
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sidthesloth.html5-boilerplate

Comment: Is it this issue; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908218/some-emmet-abbrevirations-in-vsc-not-working-like-or-using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the plugin for html has been deprecated, you can input html5 and get the tip of template

Comment: omg ı use ! (exclamation-mark) for html template auto complete , but today dont work pff

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the same happened to me a few days ago. Your emmet (or other settings) are just fine. Actually, VS Code isn't supporting '!' for HTML SYNTAX anymore.

Try typing HTML:5 to get an autocomplete option.
OR, you might just use 'doc' instead of '!' as well. Both work fine.

Answer (score 1):

first make sure that Emmet: Trigger on Tab is checked.
Then instead of typing ! then Enter key, type ! then the tab key.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c49ln.png)