# What Happened to element*# with Emmet?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

With Emmet in HTML, I used to be able to type `element*#` and it would expand into that number of elements (including all child elements, if specified). Example: If I typed `li*3` it would expand to the following

```html
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

What happened to it? Did Emmet remove that in a new version or something? Did VSCode stop supporting it? Or did some setting that I changed make it stop working?
If it is just me that is having this problem, that it has to do with my settings (or something else on my computer).

**EDIT:**
If I do `li*3>a` then it works as expected. But I don't always use it with children, and would like it to do it when I just do `element*#`

Comment: Have you updated to the most recent version of VSC? There was an issue with Emmet expansion in a recent version which I believe has been corrected. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908218/some-emmet-abbreviations-in-vsc-not-working-like-or-using

Comment: Not yet... I will update VSCode and see if that fixes it. I also added a note in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691) (see his comment for a link to more details about the issue), it now works. Apparently there was an issue with Emmet expansions, and the most recent update for VSCode fixed it. If you are having this issue, make sure you are updated, to see if that fixes it.